# TortoiseGitMerge customization

Tags: tortoisegit, tortoisemerge, tortoisegitmerge

Is there any way to make TortoiseGitMerge [image: TortoiseGitMerge] highlighted section be same as in TortoiseMerge [image: TortoiseMerge] without resizing window?

Comment: TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit should have exactly the same ribbon menu in their latest version.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried older TortoiseGit version and it has menu little closer to what I want. Wish it to be customizable.

Comment: Ribbon bars cannot be customizable by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ribbon bars are not customizable by design.

It depends on the window size whether the up and down arrows are displayed as big or small icons.